# Carriage return/line feed stopped working in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms

SQL was working fine last week with the old CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) for line feed/carriage return.

```
DECLARE @text varchar(2000)
SET @text = 
'Attached is your new reporting ID and temporary password.'
+ CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
+ 'The new login/password will be updated  on ' + Convert(char(10), @ticketdate,101)
```

Last week this ran as expected giving me nicely formatted text with a space between the lines.

This week, the same code on the same server is returning one long run-on line of text.

This seems like this is a collation issue? Or something like that?

The code has worked as expect so something changed, but I can't identify what might have changed.

This seems like it could be collation issue? But it appears to be the default latin setting.

Comment: I've been outputting it to grid. The text and file options still recognize the carriage returns, but the text gets cut off, which is why I was sending to grid.

Answer (score 11):

Since you're outputting to Grid View, I suspect that the option to *Retain CR/LF on copy or save* is disabled.  Enable this option, **open a new query window**, run the same query, and your newline characters should now come across after you paste results out of a Grid View.  In SSMS 2017, the Setting can be found under *Tools* → *Options* → *Query Results* → *SQL Server* → *Results to Grid*.  The path is in a similar location in other versions of SSMS.

[image]

Alternatively, if you want to apply this setting to the immediate query window only, enable the *Retain CR/LF on copy or save* option which can be found under *Query* → *Query Options...* → *Results* → *Grid*.  These settings won't be saved across all query windows, rather they are only applied to the current one.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to open a new query window, you can right click the query, select Query Options and go to Results > Grid and the same option is there.

Changing it in the above would update the default settings for a query window (so depends if you always want it that way or just for this instance).